# Remove dropdownlist item using css

Tags: javascript, css

we have two dropdown lists in our MOSS portal. I want to remove second item of second dropdown list on 'Page Load', not after selecting it . I tried using javascript but as i am a beginner at scripting so it is not working . So guys is there anyway i can remove that item using css .

The dropdownlist is in a user control (ascx) file . 
the dropdownlist id is 'drprequest' .
can we do it like :

```
drprequest:nth-of-child(2){display:none};
```

because i googled something similar to this one but i couldnt find anything.

If not can anyone give me the script to remove that item. Please help me friends .

Comment: is my given solution works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below CSS code to hide second option from the dropdown with ID `drprequest`

```
#drprequest select:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
```

It will hide the second child of the dropdown using the CSS.

If you want to hide any other option from dropdown than just change the number accordingly.

Comment: Is above solution works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Do you populate dropdown in your ascx.cs file? Try to process data on server-side.

## Javascript

Remove option by its position in select:

```
$("[id$='drprequest'] option:eq(1)").remove()
```

Remove option by its value:

```
$("[id$='drprequest'] option[value='{option_val}']").remove()
```

## CSS

```
[id$='drprequest'] select:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
```